# tomcat won't start in Debug mode

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging

I've been attempting to get Tomcat to start with JPDA debugging enabled.

I've tried exporting the JPDA_ADDRESS and JPDA_TRANSPORT settings.

I've uncommented the line in tomcat7 defaults.template that should enabled JPDA.

I've restarted tomcat (several times). using "sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart"

I'm unable to run the catalina.sh, as it tries using directories that don't exist, complains, and quits.

"netstat -tulpn" shows that port 8080 is open by java, but not port 8000.

So what (incredibly obvious) step am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I invoke tomcat7 with:

```
sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh jpda start
```

to debug remotely from Eclipse